# Multiple notifications for Yearling badge

Tags: bug, badges, notifications

I've received multiple notifications for the Yearling badge on cs.meta (this site) - four so far, and they keep coming.

[image: notification section; Yearling badge is displayed four times]

Comment: now up to 6 (that is 2 more in the 51 minutes since this bug report was posted)